# Images are broken on Safari Browser

Tags: jss, sitecore-api, media-library, sitecore-react

I'm using `Sitecore 9.1`, `JSS` and `ReactJS`.

Some of the images are not showing on Safari but working fine on Chrome.

Here's a sample url:

```
/-/media/Intelligence-Bank/Folder/Folder/Logo/Logo.png?h=422&w=421&hash=5E97E41EC6024EE0C649FA6F4.
```

I tried removing the query string;

```
/-/media/Intelligence-Bank/Folder/Folder/Logo/Logo.png?
```

still not working.

Comment: Is your Safari capable to show the .png? what do you get when try view the image, what http status code e,t,c

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a generic issue with PNG Images not a Sitecore Issue 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43526442/png-format-images-do-not-display-on-mac-safari